# How to read space separated key of an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables

Help would be appreciated,to read key from an object, the key is separated with space

```
var Obj = {
    student class: '4th',
    student roll: '24'
}

console.log(obj.student class) ? throws error.
console.log(obj.student roll) ? throws error.
```

Comment: The real question is why you should have spaces in your keys!

Comment: Giving spaces in property names is _Bad practice_!

Comment: and not using quotes if you have not allowed character is an error, like spaces for instance

Comment: @elio.d : this is how i am getting it from API.

Comment: honestly you should complain ;)

Comment: @elio.d: I did it ;) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in quotes and use bracket notation.

```
var Obj = {
  'student class': '4th',
  'student roll': '24'
};

console.log(Obj['student class']);
console.log(Obj['student roll']);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the square brackets notation:
`object['property name']`

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to read fields within the object

1. object.field
2. object[field]

To access fields having spaces you have to use second option

console.log(Obj['student class']);
console.log(Obj['student roll']);